# group nearby timestamps together in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I understand Pandas has a `pd.Grouper` where we can specify time frequency. However, it uses the frequency as border for each sample, similar to how resample does it.
For example:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Timestamp', freq='1s')).agg({...})
```

will create a grouped dataframe with index that are `1s` apart.
However, I want to group all rows where the difference between the previous and next rows are less than `1s`. For example, my timestamp might be (ignoring datetimes for simplicity, only showing the seconds, assume the same datetime before second precision) `1.1s, 1.8s, 2.4s, 5s, 5.9s, 9s`, in which case I want `(1.1s, 1.8s, and 2.4s)`, `(5s, 5.9s)`, `(9s)` grouped together, and the indexes to the grouped dataframe are `(1.1s, 5s, 9s)`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can groupby cumsum on (diff > threshold):

```
threshold = pd.Timedelta('1s')

blocks = df['Timestamp'].diff().ge(threshold).cumsum()

df.groupby(blocks).agg({...})
```

**Note**: the question is inherently problematic, e.g. if the `Timestamp` is something like `pd.date_range('2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', freq='.9s')`, then you'd have just one big group.

1. Create a threshold of 1 second
2. Create a new column that is the difference between the current timestamp and the previous timestamp
3. Create a new column that is a cumulative sum of the difference between the current timestamp and the previous timestamp
4. Group by the new column and aggregate the data